# Advertisement Video Production

Tags: after-effects, premiere

So there's this type of video I want to make, but not sure what type it is called and not sure where to refer to when looking for examples on how to make one.

This is an [iPhone Ad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeoUELDgyM4)  from last year and it is what I want to try and recreate.

How would you make this kind of video?

Comment: I'd also suggest that video might not be worth copying.  It's honestly a pretty horrible video.  The text moves way too fast to be meaningful and takes too much of the time.  I couldn't even finish watching the video despite trying to watch it to offer feedback.  They use some decent artistic decisions in clip selection, but it wasn't enough to hold the video together for me.  Without compelling content that people have a pre-vested interest in wanting to know about, I doubt that this style of video would be an effective means of presentation for your content.

Comment: Related https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14974/how-to-improve-sense-of-timing-in-motion-graphics

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/3832/how-best-to-find-literature-on-motion-graphics-design

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8316/software-advice-for-producing-video-ads

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13082/what-are-motion-graphics/

Comment: A note on the closure.  It isn't exactly a duplicate of the closed as duplicate, but to the extent we can cover this kind of thing here, the basic answer for high production value motion graphics is generally hire someone.  The other questions I linked will give some more direction on further reading if you really want to try doing it yourself, but this particular topic has been covered in a much more general sense pretty in depth.  If you have a more specific question about some aspect of how to make the video after looking at those, please feel free to post a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hire a [video editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_editor).

Questions like yours often hint at a common misconception that all one needs to create great video content is the right piece of software, and once one has found the right software creating an awesome piece of video content becomes a matter of pressing a couple of buttons. This is incorrect.

The technical side of the video you linked is actually pretty straightforward. It consists of basically two interspersed parts/styles:

- Product shots & video. Most of them seem to be normal videos, though some of them look like well-done 3D-animations to me. For the latter you will indeed need a fair amount of technical expertise.
- Animated text. FOr this video especially, it's not that hard to do *technically*. It's just some text that is animated in and out, intertwined with video footage. You could probably do all of that in Premiere Pro. Your choice of video editing software doesn't really matter here. [Pick one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_editing_software).

What makes that video great however is **not** the technical implementation. It's the aesthetic & stylistic choices made during filming and editing. Watch the video again and appreciate the following aspects:

- Lighting and light/shadow contrasts (during the live action footage)
- Montage (i.e. how are the individual parts stitched together)
- Coordination of sound and video (notice how the cuts correspond to the beats of the music?)
- Pacing (the sequence of fast-and-slow parts,  e.g. the pacing changes at TC 0:10, 0:19 and 0:30)
- Emphasis of certain parts, again using nothing but light and dark (regarding the background color, but also the way this is intersperces with low-key and high-key footage)
- Transitions. Those are very short and easy to miss, but there are some great match cuts between text and video elements there (e.g. at TC 0:57, notice how the text moving to the right transitions to the shot of the ballon hitting the iPhone?)
- ... and much more.

All of those subtle aesthetic decisions are what people study and exercise for years. The study of video editing (or any creative/artistic field really) is really not about how to use a piece of software, but rather about aesthetics (which btw. has little to do with pretty or beautiful stuff, but is the study of *perception*). Which is why learning a piece of software, no matter how sophisticated, won't get you very far. Instead, focus on learning aesthetics and finding your own style, then your choice of software won't matter.

If you are interested in learning more on that subject, check out my answer here: [Good learning resources for 'non-technical' aspects of filmmaking](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16389/good-learning-resources-for-non-technical-aspects-of-filmmaking/16399#16399). Otherwise - and this brings me back to my initial point - hire a video editor.